# How can I find the 1000 most commonly spoken German phrases?

Tags: vocabulary

I think this is probably going to be far more useful than knowing the 1000 most used words, it is always easier to remember a word in context.

I tried Chat on you.com and it ran out after 42 results.
Google just gave me a 3hr video of someone reading stuff out slowly.

Any other ideas as to how I could get such a list or if such a thing exists in Anki?

Comment: How do you determine or define 'most spoken'? How long till it is no phrase anymore?

Comment: If you could list all the phrases and sentences that were ever spoken by anyone, rank them from most to least used and pick the top 1000

Comment: I'm not convinced the question is on-topic for the site since you could ask the same question for English. It also needs clarification; what exactly to you mean by a "phrase"? There's a grammatical definition, several words that make up a sentence element. Or it might mean something like two to five words strung together. Also, what context/register are you talking about? Spoken/written, formal/informal?

Comment: There is no such database nor could it exist which contains all phrases ever spoken. Even for written language that's an impossible task: you have no access to my private documents. Also 'phrase' needs definition. What is a phrase? Is a sentence a sequence of phrases? If so: what's the distinction? What's the distinction to 'single word'? Even if you had all texts available: how do you separate a text into single phrases? What would be the phrases you extract from this comment or let alone this sentence? I'm not sure the question is well-posed, thus not sure whether it is currently answerable.

Comment: It doesn't have to be 100pc accurate. Just have a bot look at transcripts of all possible spoken texts either say 'speech in novels', dialog in film scripts, auto transcribed videos for use with CC. Then break them down into sentences. Rank by frequency of occurrence

Comment: Would your goal be to become an active German speaker through the use of spaced repetition systems such as Anki? If so, then I could provide you with a proposal on that in this comments section. An official answer would be off-topic!

Comment: I am not sure this is a question about the German language. Sounds more like a data retrieval problem.

Comment: @JonathanScholbach I think it's both. I am not sure you could take a generic solution and point it at 'german' and get the expected results back.

Comment: @SatishVasan I think Anki would be a useful tool for working with the dataset in question

Comment: If you would like to use a spaced repetition system (SRS) as a tool for learning to use German phrases, I have found it works best if you collect the phrases that you want to learn (from books, radio, etc) and then input them into the SRS as an audio clip into the question section and then type the phrase into the answer section. For a "Fully correct rating" on the card, you must be able to repeat the phrase out loud, exactly the same as the audio clip.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has nothing to do with the German language per se.

Comment: I think after #50 or so, the statistics will get rather squishy - the usage statistics of all phrases is probably a gaussian with a looooooong tail, and given the unclear definition of what a phrase is (or when it starts to be another phrase), and the open-ness of the corpus of spoken language, the placement of phrases post-50 will be very variable (#250 or #2500 ? - depends on this one example); Plus, the very often-used ones are very regional 'Weisch?' ('you know?') will be heard constantly on the streets of south-west Germany, not at all in north-east.